# Passing values in to ajax loaded functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I have a function that loads "chunks of content" on to my page which I refer to as a component ...

```
function loadComponent(container, componentName, callback) {
    api.get("Core/Component/Render()?AppId=" + session.app.Id + "&Name=" + componentName, function (result) {
            container.append(result.value);
            if (callback) { callback(result.value); }
    });
}
```

api.get simply does an ajax call.

Typically when i use this I do something like this ...

```
var app = { ... };

loadComponent($("some selector"), "ComponentName", function(e) {
    ComponentName.init(app);
});
```

Recently i noticed that "app" iniside the init function is always undefined.
If I put a break point in the callback function (or a debugger statement) the browser skips it and drops in to the init and stops there.

If I put a breakpoint / debugger statement before the loadComponent call I see that the value "app" is correctly populated and not undefined.

Can anyone explain what might cause this behaviour?

Update:

Ok so I have this function in which I make the call more than once like so ...

```
expand: function (e) {
    var theApp = GetApp();

    loadComponent($(".tab[name=cultures]", container), "CultureManagement", function (c) { CultureManagement.init(theApp, $("[name=cultures]", container)); });
    loadComponent($(".tab[name=templates]", container), "TemplateManagement", function (c) { TemplateManagement.init(theApp, $("[name=templates]", container)); });
    loadComponent($(".tab[name=layouts]", container), "LayoutManagement", function (c) { LayoutManagement.init(theApp, $("[name=layouts]", container)); });
    loadComponent($(".tab[name=components]", container), "ComponentManagement", function (c) { ComponentManagement.init(theApp, $("[name=components]", container)); });
    loadComponent($(".tab[name=resources]", container), "Resourcing", function (c) { Resourcing.init(theApp, $("[name=resources]", container)); });
    loadComponent($(".tab[name=packaging]", container), "PackageManagement", function (c) { PackageManagement.init(theApp, $("[name=PackageManagement]", container)); });
    loadComponent($(".tab[name=roles]", container), "UserManagement", function (c) { UserManagement.init(theApp, $("[name=roles]", container)); });
```

Strangley, for some on the first line of the init call "theApp" is undefined and for others it isn't. what a peculiar situation.

Comment: Where is `ComponentName.init()` defined?

Comment: In the content that loadComponent got from the server, it pulls a block of markup + a script. I have a standard that I pass the container element + the app information in to the init call which all components have ... the component is just an object that contains an init function + whatever else it needs to do it's thing.

Comment: Are `app` and the call to `loadComponent` in the very same compilation unit? If so, the `app` should be correctly captured in the closure, together with its value.

Comment: @WiktorZychla not sure what you mean ... the value is populated, I call up a new script from the server, add it to the page and pass it my value ... then it's undefined. The init function consumed in the callback doesn't exist until that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the call was not coming from my load block but instead from the component code itself which does this ...

```
$(function() { 
      var me = document.currentScript;
      if($(me).closest("[name=grid]").length === 0) { PackageManagement.init(); } 
});
```

... this is supposed to only call init on the component if the component doesn't have a parent grid component in to which it's being loaded.

Apparently i need to rethink this logic.